Stuck in sleep mode
After executing the following command:
systemctl suspend
(on Ubuntu 24.04), my laptop enters sleep mode, but I am unable to wake it up by pressing the power button or any other keys.
Additionally, when I attempt to power off the laptop, it does not fully shut down. The keyboard LEDs remain on, and the Fn+Esc (FnLk) key light stays on as well.
Built-in keyboard | Lenovo ThinkPad P50 | Nvidia Quadro M2000M | Ubuntu 24.04

Please [edit] your question and add: i) Ubuntu version and flavor (kubuntu, lubuntu, etc); ii) details about your hardware, your graphics card etc (see inxi), iii) does it wake up if you press the power on button? iv) is the keyboard built in or external USB? The more detail you can give us, the better we will be able to help you.

done.
Is there any solution for that?

you could try disabling your nvidia hibernation settings:
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-resume.service

sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume.service

sudo rm /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia

Can I retrieve files from trash after it has been emptied?

Doesn't work :(
If these the removed file is useful or important tell me how to restore it : )
